# Translation of Monty Python's "And now for something completely different"

Tags: anglais

Is there a translation of the Monty Python quote "And now for something completely different" that is actually recognized by some French speakers as a reference?

Comment: Are you looking for a similar reference to the Monty Python or to a similar cliché?

Comment: A reference to Monty Python.

Comment: Someone wants to close this as "too localized"? I guess that counts as the answer "No" to my question.

Comment: A "no" would be a better answer than a closure, until the Monthy Python make it enough into French culture for a "yes" to be posted :·)

Answer (score 12):

I don't know of any official translation. I'll propose *et maintenant, sans transition* (literally: “and now with no transition” [to ease the change of topic]). It, like “and now for something completely different”, was a catchphrase of a TV presenter (maybe not from the same generation) used as a transition phrase between two topics in a TV program. I think that presenter was [Patrick Poivre d'Arvor](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Poivre_d%27Arvor), who presented the TV news program with the largest audience in France for two decades, though I don't know whether it originated with him. The phrase [gets a lot of use](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22et+maintenant+sans+transition%22), I think most French people today will recognize it as something they've heard before (even I do, and I've probably never watched that news program).

Comment: Sounds more like a *Les guignols de l'info*'s gimmick.

Comment: @Evpok I'm no TV buff, but as far as I know, the catchphrase is genuinely from PPDA, and the *Guignols* used it because it would be recognized as such, much like the Monty Pythons expected their audience to recognize “and now for something completely different”.

Comment: What makes it a reference could be *Les guignols de l'info*, even if it originates from PPDA. That's how I guess it sounds familiar to me too, without having watched any more than a handful of times.

Answer (score 5):

I've just found the answer in “The Pythons Autobiography by The Pythons”. French version is:

> Et maintenant quelque chose tout à fait différent

I guess it's the best translation we can get.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the series was widely known in France so the reference will not be recognized by many people. In fact I would say the english version might be as much recognized as the translation used in the dubbed version which is "*Et maintenant, quelque chose de différent.*"

Answer (score 2):

The series has been dubbed [*La première folie des Monty Pythons*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Premi%C3%A8re_Folie_des_Monty_Python) (The Monty Pythons' First Folly), but the original title is almost always used as far as I can tell. As far as I know, there is no official translation of the phrase itself ; I have actually seen it used as is in French (granted, from English literate persons).